# how to loop div contents, not the div itself

Tags: reactjs

I want to loop through all errors and show them in a bootstrap alert div, not each item show up in its own alert div.

This is obviously outputting a div for each error which isn't what I want.

```
      {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) &&
        this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
          <div key={index} className="alert alert-danger">
            {error.name}
            {error.email}
            {error.password}
          </div>
        ))}
```

And if I do this then when the page loads I have an empty red div sitting there.

```
      <div className="alert alert-danger">
        {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) &&
          this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              {error.name}
              {error.email}
              {error.password}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `<div className="alert ...` is visible even without any content, then you need to separate the condition from the map like this:

```
  {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) && (
    <div className="alert alert-danger">
      {this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {error.name}
          {error.email}
          {error.password}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )}
```

Comment: Yep, this is exactly what I need!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
          {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) && this.state.errors.length > 0 && (
            <div className='alert alert-danger'>
              {this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
                <div key={index}>
                  {error.name}
                  {error.email}
                  {error.password}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          )}
```

Comment: good point with the `this.state.errors.length` if the array can be empty instead of undefined for zero errors

Answer (score 1):

You should keep your div outside the loop if you want one of them. Then wrap each error message in a `span` or element of your choice. Something like this:

```
<div key={index} className="alert alert-danger">
  {Array.isArray(this.state.errors) &&
    this.state.errors.map((error, index) => (
      <span key={index}>
        {error.name}
        {error.email}
        {error.password}
      </span>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: And also, if I just remove the index in the first line I get the same problem as I mentioned in my question which is that when the page loads, I have an empty red div showing. It should only show upon form submission if there are validation errors.

Comment: @user10980228 maybe post a bit more of your code, sounds like maybe you have a few additional errors that need to be worked out.

Comment: Aprillion's solution should fix the issue with the div showing up right off the bat @user10980228

Answer (score 0):

Just map through your error inside the alert div and add an inner element for each error. Here is an example:

```
<div className="alert alert-danger">
  {
     this.state.errors
        .map((error, index) =>(
          <p key={index} className="error">
              {error.name}
              {error.email}
              {error.password}           
          </p>
        ))
  }
</div>
```

```js
const errs = [
  {
    name: 'Name',
    email: 'Email',
    password: 'Password'
  }, {
    name: 'Name',
    email: 'Email',
    password: 'Password'
  }, {
    name: 'Name',
    email: 'Email',
    password: 'Password'
  }
]

class Errors extends React.Component {

  state = {
    errors: null
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate (lastProps) {
    if (lastProps.errors && !this.props.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: null })
    }
    
    if (!lastProps.errors && this.props.errors) {
      this.setState({ errors: errs })
    }
    
  }
  
  render () {
    const { errors } = this.state
    
    if (!Array.isArray(errors) || errors.length === 0) {
      return null
    }
    
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger">
        {
          errors.map((error, index) => (
            <p key={index} className="error">
              {error.name}
              {error.email}
              {error.password}
            </p>
          ))
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const App = () => {
  const [ withErrors, setWithErrors ] = React.useState(false);
  const toggleErrors = () => setWithErrors(state => !state);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Errors errors={ withErrors ? true : false } />
      <button onClick={ toggleErrors }>
        { withErrors ? 'Remove errors' : 'Add errors' }
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render((<App />), document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I am getting an 'unexpected token' error trying to use your code

Comment: Yes I left some extra brackets. But the code snippet should be ok